# How do I replace the arrayofconst in C #

Tags: c#, c++builder

I'm going through my system C++ to C# and now I'm hooked on ARRAYOFCONST and I have no idea how to replace same function in C#. Does anyone have any ideas that might help me?

```
public int IntToCoord(int coordenada)
    {
        string resultado;

        resultado = "0";
        coordenada = (coordenada / 10);

        resultado = resultado + string.Format("%2d", ARRAYOFCONST(((coordenada/3600))));

        coordenada = (coordenada / 3600);

        resultado = resultado + string.Format("%2d", ARRAYOFCONST(((coordenada/60))));

        coordenada = (coordenada / 60);

        resultado = resultado + string.Format("%2d", ARRAYOFCONST((coordenada)));

        while (resultado.Pos(" ") > 0)

            resultado[resultado.Pos(" ")] = '0';

        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: `I'm going through my system ++ c to C #` - What?

Comment: @HighCore he is moving from c++ to c#, don't curse him for not being able to properly use English.

Comment: @Prix you're right. though `++ c` doesn't look like a thing, not even in spanish (which is my native language too, btw)

Comment: Maybe you want to try asking at http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ if you feel more comfortable using your own language.

Comment: Throughout my application. But in C ++ ARRAYOFCONST use this method, and I have no knowledge in C # that I can use to replace.

Comment: @HighCore his code looks like Portuguese or so I assume.

Comment: you can use simple `string.Format("{0}",coordenada/60)` :-)

Comment: @Vache `#define ARRAYOFCONST(values) \ 
   OpenArray<TVarRec>values, OpenArrayCount<TVarRec>values.GetHigh()`

Comment: I don't speak english very well. I have te used Google Translator.

Comment: human languages aside, your code doesn't make any sense. Your method returns `int` but you're returning a `string`. And doing a weird character manipulation of the string which is also invalid. **What are you really trying to do?** C++ and C# are very different and the approach you take on each is different too.

Comment: @user2254936 you can ask your question here http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ in your own language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

format for `string.Format` function in C# have a few difference from in C++
for using it you need just string template and list of parameters
So in your case you need

```
string.Format("{0,2}",coordenada)
```

instead of

```
string.Format("%2d", ARRAYOFCONST((coordenada)))
```

more info on MSDN: [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx)